# SSL certificate installation issue in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I try to install the SSL certificate in my AWS ec2. Here are the steps which I follow.

> 1 - Request certificate from certificate manager services.
>
> 2 - Verify the certificate with the DNS method(Add Cname record in
>   hosted zone of the domain).
>
> 3 - Make a load balancer and install the certificate in ec2 instance.
>   4 - Add .htaccess www and https redirect for the URL.

But when I open my website, it still shows 'Not Secure'. When I try to check the SSL certificate via 'Online SSL Checker'. I didn't find my certificate. It shows some error 'No SSL certificates were found on domain.com. Make sure that the name resolves to the correct server and that the SSL port (default is 443) is open on your server's firewall.'. Please help.

Comment: can you check this and tried ? https://aboutssl.org/install-ssl-certificate-amazon-web-services-aws/

Comment: Is the domain name resolving to the load balancer? Is the cert installed on the load balancer or on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following

- If there is a HTTPS listener in your load balancer
- The security group
  attached to the load balancer allows HTTPS traffic from port 443
- You have added a alias `A Record` in your domain name pointing to the dns hostname of your elastic load balancer

Comment: i cross-checked all the points mentioned by you. There is not an issue in the mentioned points. Here is a detailed overview of the following points.

Comment: The problem here is that the SSL certificate is installed in your load balancer and not your EC2 instance. The SSL termination happens on your load balancer and your website should work on HTTPS. Access the load balancer URL in the browser with HTTPS and if it works then change the A record to point to the hostname of the load balancer

Comment: When I open the load balancer URL in the browser, it shows HTTP 503 error.

Comment: Please check whether you have registered your EC2 instance in the target group of your load balancer. If you are using an Application load balancer you can follow the following guide to register instances if not done https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-register-targets.html